# Ubuntu install formated my 2nd SSD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, hard-drive, ssd

I installed Ubuntu on a separate, newly bought SSD because I needed to set up dual boot with windows 10. In the process my main m.2 SSD with windows on it was formated (it says unlocated space). How could this even happen, I carefuly worked my way though the installation, making sure I create all of the files on my Sata drive and select this and only this drive for formatting.

Is there any way of recovering my files?

Answer (score 1):

One of the nice things about Ubuntu is that it (almost) always does exactly what you tell it. Unfortunately, one of the bad things about Ubuntu is that it (almost) always does *exactly* what you tell it ... even if it's not what you *meant*. I've installed just about every version of Ubuntu since Warty and the only time I've made a mistake was when I misunderstood a sentence that was probably revised once too often. That said, it may be possible to restore your Windows partition so long as no data has been written to that device. To do this, you'll need `testdisk`.

First, let's open a Terminal, then:

0. Update `apt`, as we need to grab some software: `sudo apt update`
1. Install `testdisk`: `sudo apt install testdisk`
2. Ensure the application is installed correctly with a recent version, such as 7.1: `testdisk --version`

```
TestDisk 7.1, Data Recovery Utility, July 2019
Christophe GRENIER <grenier@cgsecurity.org>
https://www.cgsecurity.org

Version: 7.1
Compiler: GCC 9.2
ext2fs lib: 1.45.5, ntfs lib: libntfs-3g, reiserfs lib: none, ewf lib: none, curses lib: ncurses 6.1
OS: Linux, kernel 5.4.0-58-generic (#64-Ubuntu SMP Wed Dec 9 08:16:25 UTC 2020) x86_64
```

With this out of the way, we can get into the actual recovery steps. First we will need to create a detailed log file.

3. Start the `testdisk` wizard with: `sudo testdisk`

[image: Testdisk Wizard]

***Note:** If you do not use `sudo` here, you will be asked for a `sudo` password after choosing an option.*

4. You can use the arrow keys to navigate between `[Create]`, `[Append]`, and `[No Log]` but, as this is the first time you're running the tool and we most certainly need a log, just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. You'll be presented a list of devices to recover. Unfortunately there will likely be a bunch of `/dev/loopX` records getting in the way, but you should find your Windows device somewhere as `/dev/nvmeXnY` or `/dev/sdXY`, where `X` is the device number and `Y` is the partition number. Use the <kbd>⇡</kbd> and <kbd>⇣</kbd> arrow keys to choose the partition that you would like to recover, then use the <kbd>⇠</kbd> and <kbd>⇢</kbd> arrow keys to toggle between `[Proceed ]` and `[  Quit  ]`.

[image: Choose Your Parition]

Next, it's time to set the partition table type.

6. You'll be presented yet another list of options to choose from, this time partition table types. `testdisk` is pretty good at choosing the correct one for you and, because Windows uses NTFS partitions, you will probably have `[Intel  ]` pre-selected. You shouldn't need to change this so long as the device itself has not been modified or damaged.

[image: Choose Your Partition Type]

7. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to continue
8. The next page is going to ask what you would like to do. As we are trying to recover a lost partition, we are going to choose `[Analyze]`

[image: What to do, what to do]

9. Next you'll see a list like in the image below with `[Quick Search]` highlighted. This will scan your drive to find any partition information, past or present. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image: Encrypted! Unknown!]

10. The utility will need a bit of time (possibly hours) to scan through the entire device. When it's done, it will list any partitions that it found.

***Note:** I don't have any lost NTFS partitions in the house, so I can't (easily) show you what that might look like.*

11. You will likely see multiple partitions for boot, Windows, and possibly system recovery, depending on how Windows was configured on your device. Choose one and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to choose the next action.
12. When all partitions are available, the data should be correctly listed with the size of the partition and `NTFS` as its format. If this is good, you can use the <kbd>⇠</kbd> and <kbd>⇢</kbd> arrows to select `[Write]`. This will save the partition structure to the disk and, ideally, bring your Windows installation back to life!
13. Choose `[Quit]` to exit the application and, when it asks you to reboot, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to trigger the `[Ok]`.

This *should* give you your Windows installation back or, at the very least, make the partitions readable so that you can recover your files.

Hope this makes your day a little brighter

Comment: Do this from live installer, as if you did overwrite Windows, you will not be able to recover data that is overwritten and use of system will overwrite more data. Windows typically writes at beginning of partition and Linux writes randomly and is smaller than Windows. You do have backups?

Comment: I have backups of my backups. Heck, I have backups of my backup server in case my backups are corrupted over time! The *non-replaceable* files are written to a trio of 100GB BD-R XL discs on the first of every month, too. That said, I should test the restore process more often. Right now it's just twice a year due to time constraints.

Comment: Thank you good Sir, you are the man!