# Can I restore the data from a USB that was removed unsafely?

Tags: 20.04, external-hdd, restore

During copying some files to my external hard drive, I accidentally disconnected the USB from my laptop. I lost all files in the directory to which I had been copying some files.

Question: Is it possible to find the content of this directory somewhere? Or is there a way how to restore them? Thank you for your help.

Comment: The `testdisk` utility might help. [This answer goes through the steps of using it](https://askubuntu.com/a/1309268/1091774).

Comment: If you copied files, the original files on your laptop will still be there.

Comment: Or did you move them?

Comment: Original files are not there. The usb seems to have lost the reference to it. I am using photorec, I will tell soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To everyone, I solved it using `PhotoRec`. Great tool for retrieving lost files from external hard drive.